# Galois extension of prime degree

Tags: galois-theory

I don't understand a step in the proof of corollary 96 in the book "Galois Theory" by J. Rotman.
The full book can be found here https://epdf.pub/galois-theory-second-edition-universitext.html

**Corollary 96**:
Let $E / F$ be a Galois extension of prime degree $p$. If $F$ has
a primitive $p$th root of unity, then $E = F(\beta)$, where $\beta^p \in F$, and so $E / F$
is a pure extension.

Here is the beginning of the proof:

**Proof**:
If $\omega$ is a primitive $p$th root of unity, then $N(\omega) = \omega^p = 1$, because
$\omega \in F$. Now $Gal(E/F) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p$, by Corollary 71, hence is cyclic; let $\sigma$ be a generator. ...

($N$ denotes the norm.) And Corollary 71 says:

**Corollary 71**:
Let $p$ be a prime, let $F$ be a field containing a primitive $p$th
root of unity, and let $f(x) = x^p - c \in F[x]$ have splitting field $E$. Then
either $f(x)$ splits and $Gal(E/F) = 1$ or it is irreducible and $Gal(E/F) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p$.

My question: I do not see how $Gal(E/F) \simeq \mathbb{Z}_p$ follows from Corollary 71. Isn't it true that every group of prime order $p$ is cyclic and isomorph to $\mathbb{Z}_p$? Have I overseen something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, Corollary 71 is not relevant and you only have to observe that every group of order $p$ is cyclic.

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: It's perhaps worth mentioning that Rotman has at least one other book that sort of famously has a lot of errata: https://faculty.math.illinois.edu/~rotman/errhomalg.pdf